# Replace the Contents inside Azure Storage

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, azure-storage

Is there are any way to replace a file if the same name exists? I can't see any replace method in Azure Storage. Here is my code:

```
var client = new CloudBlobClient(
      new Uri(" http://sweetapp.blob.core.windows.net/"), credentials);
var container = client.GetContainerReference("cakepictures");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
var perm = new BlobContainerPermissions();
perm.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
await container.SetPermissionsAsync(perm);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(newfilename + i + file.FileType);
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Is there anything that I could add into this code so that it replaces existing or same file name?

Comment: I think, the only way is to execute steps: delete and upload new.

Comment: oh is that so. how im going to manage my storage? is there are any other method? if there is no such a method then my storage will gonna get larger and larger. :3

Comment: If you delete file before uploading new one, it would not get larger

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If a blob exists in blob storage and if you upload another file with the same name as that of the blob, old blob contents will automatically be replaced with the contents of new file. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists - doesn't work in my case, i use BlobClient from azure.storage.blob (azure-storage-blob==12.2.0, python 3.10.4)

Comment: UPD:  
solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132689/azureblob-upload-errorthe-specified-blob-already-exists

Answer (score 2):

As Gaurav also mentioned in his answer, the default behavior of UploadFromStream API is to overwrite if the blob already exists.