# Error 500 when replacing file in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage

Good day, I'm having an error where when I replace a file, it returns "500 internal server error". But when I upload a new file everything is okay.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task UploadContentBlobAsync(IFormFile formFile, string fileName)
{
    var blobClient = _containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(formFile.OpenReadStream());
}
```

accoring to this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039193/replace-the-contents-inside-azure-storage) Azure will just replace my fie to be uploaded to the existing file, but that doesn't happen to my case.

Comment: Are you sure that the 500 error is coming from storage and not from your web application?

Comment: I'm using POSTMAN so I don't know. Maybe from my web application, any tips to improve my code so I can Replace existing files on my blob storage? I can replace manually using Azure Storage Explorer. So maybe my code is the problem.

Comment: Any details error? Any way, if you upload file that already exists, You should use this:`await blobClient.UploadAsync(yourstream, true);` . The bool value is false by default.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: Haven't tested it yet. I paused the development on this one. Will get back to you once we resumed dev on uploading images.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.4.3`, I create a method and pass the request as a parameter. The following code works and no error will be reported during the replacement of blob content:

```
string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

string containerName = "video";

string fileName = "1.png";

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

await blobClient.UploadAsync(req.Body, true);
```

(I put the picture in the binary format and put it in the request.)

In the package I use, the Boolean value of parameter of the UploadAsync method about whether to override blob is false, so I must provide a true, otherwise it will report an error.

You can make an experiment to see if it can be executed correctly according to the package version and code provided by me. If not, please provide detail error information.:)